# How to extract the first element (as a list of string) of the n-th elements of a nested list, Python

Tags: python, list

I am a fresh python beginner and trying to extract the first element of the first n-th elements of a nested list. But it doesn't work so far.

Say:

```
list = [["Anna","w",15],["Peter","m",20],["Zani","m",10], ["Lily","w",19]]
```

Goal:

```
list_new = ['Anna','Peter','Zani'...(#until the n-th elements)]
```

If I want to first element of all the elements in the list, it should be:

```
for i in list:
    for j in i:
        print j[0]
```

But what if i only want to strip the first element of the n-th elements of the list, instead of all the elements.

For example for the first 2 elements:
I tried:

```
for i in list[0:2]:
    for j in i:
        print j[0]
```

but it didn't work.

What's more, if i want to give the value of n later by using

```
def sheet(list, n)
```

and the return statement, how could i do it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Side note: *never* name a variable after a built-in class, e.g. use `L` or `lst` instead of `list`.

Comment: @jpp variables should not start with caps so 'l' instead of 'L' (pep8)

Comment: @CorentinLimier, `l` is a *big* "no". In many fonts, it is confused with capital `I`. In any case, the point about shadowing built-ins is different and far more important. You **never** want to override built-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, list is reserved for the built-in function `list()` in python, you should not use 'list' as variable name.

To get the first element of each nested list :

```
l = [["Anna","w",15],["Peter","m",20],["Zani","m",10], ["Lily","w",19]]
for e in l:
     print(e[0])
```

Prints :

```
Anna
Peter
Zani
Lily
```

To do the same on the nth first elements :

```
def sheet(l, n):
    return [e[0] for e in l[:n]]

sheet(l, 3)
```

Returns

```
['Anna', 'Peter', 'Zani']
```

---

**EDIT**

```
def sheet(l, n):
    for e in l[:n]
        return [e[0]]
```

This code only returns `['Anna']` because the `return` statement stops the function. The for loop is stopped at the first element.

```
def sheet(l, n):
    return [e[0] for e in l[:n]]
```

is equivalent to :

```
def sheet(l, n):
    result = [e[0] for e in l[:n]]
    return result
```

which is equivalent to :

```
def sheet(l, n):
    result = []
    for e in l[:n]:
        result.append(e[0])
    return result
```

The for loop can ends before the return statement.

More informations [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps).

Comment: Thank you very much!! but the expected result should be a list of string -> ["Anna", "Peter","Zani"]

Comment: result IS a list of strings @SuwanWang

Comment: I see! Thank you!!

Comment: Hey @Corentin Limier! Could you please also explain what is the difference between return [e[0] for e in l[:n]] and for e in  l[:n]] \n return [e[0]]. With the second one, it only returns ["Anna"]. But the logic seems the same. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [["Anna","w",15],["Peter","m",20],["Zani","m",10], ["Lily","w",19]]
n = 2
print(lst[n][0])
```

Output:
Zani

---Updated answer for the details added in the question---

```
l = [["Anna","w",15],["Peter","m",20],["Zani","m",10], ["Lily","w",19]]
n = 2
for i in range(n):
  print(l[i][0])
```

Output:

Anna

Peter

Comment: Does not answer the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension. Given an input list of lists `L`:

```
L_new = [i[0] for i in L[:n]]
```

Functionally, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). In addition, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to avoid creating an intermediary list:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import islice

L_new = list(map(itemgetter(0), islice(L, 0, n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one which will be **easier** for you to understand:

```
n = int(input())

lst = [["Anna","w",15],["Peter","m",20],["Zani","m",10], ["Lily","w",19]]
lst_new = []

for item in lst[:n]:
    name, *rest = item
    lst_new.append(name)
```

Comment: easier ? with *rest ? This is advanced python

Comment: I would not say it is advanced one. At least it is easier to visualize. *rest just get all elements after the first one.